# Select by frequency

Tags: sql

I have two tables, like that:

```
users(id, name)
phones(user_id, number)
```

I'd like to select all user's names that are in more than three rows in the table phones. How can I do that?

Comment: This is a pretty basic aggregation query.  Have you tried anything?  If so, please edit the question and include it.  Also, tag the question with the database you are using.

Comment: And, just to clarify, the user *name* is not in the `phones` table.  Presumably you mean no `user_id` appears more than three times or have a unique index on `name` so know there are no duplicates in the `users` table.

Comment: I mean the name of the users..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the tables and add a having clause that limits the results returned by the count of the user_ids

```
select name, 
count(user_id)
from users u
join phones p
on u.id = p.user_id
group by name
having count(user_id) > 3
```

**SQL Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c5516/2

Answer (score 1):

select name from user
  join phones on id = user_id
Group By user_id
Having Count(number) > 3